# Add new user and manage his roles

Tags: magento-1.6

If I want to add new users who access the Magneto and how can I give them permissions to access some menus as Catalog , system ...etc and they didn't access others how can I do it.

Answer (score 0):

I had solved this issue from System > permission > users , role and I followed all steps and solved my issue